# How do I read multiple CSV files to sort data in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

So, my Java project has two CSV files that needs to read and print some sort the data from high to low.

First CSV file has date, location, new_cases, new_deaths, total_cases, total_deaths format.

Second CSV file has Country, location, continent, population_year, population format.

What I'm trying to do is to read both data, run a function to calculate continent data, and come up with continent(string), total_cases(int) and sort it according to high to low. then print the whole thing

Example output:

Continent (continent, csv2): ------  Total Cases:(total_cases,csv1)

Oceania 123456

Australia 12345

Europe 123

The code I wrote so far included below, please help me with deriving and sorting the data.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.* ;
public class Main {

    static void loadData() {

        String pathFile1 = "./locations.csv";
        String pathFile2 = "./full_data.csv";
        String row;
        try {

            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile1));

            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(row);
            }
            csvReader.close();


            csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile2));

            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(row);

            }
            csvReader.close();


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void add() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = -1;
        System.out.println("*************************************************************");
        System.out.println("**** COVID 19 Global Statistics *****************************");
        System.out.println("*************************************************************");
        do {
            System.out.println("[1] Load Data From Files");
            System.out.println("[2] Print Continents Total Cases (Lowest to Highest)");
            System.out.println("[3] Print Continents Total Cases (Highest to Lowest)");
            System.out.println("[4] Print Continents Total Deaths (Lowest to Highest)");
            System.out.println("[5] Print Continents Total Deaths (Highest to Lowest)");
            System.out.println("[6] Prioritize top countries for testing based on new cases per 1 million");
            System.out.println("[7] To Exit");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice:");
            choice = scnr.nextInt();
            Map<String, Integer> hm1;
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Loading files ...");
                    loadData();
                    System.out.println("Files loaded successfully!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:

                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:

                var requestedNum = scnr.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Continent:        Total Cases:");

                    break;
                case 6:
                System.out.println("How many countries to pull from the priorities list:");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using our system..Goodbye!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please a choice 1 - 7");
                    break;
            }
        } while (choice != 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `continent` at position 3 and `total` at position 5, read the first file and get the `total cases` and I guess every row in the first file related to the same row in the second file.

Then create a map with continent and number related to that continent and sort based on the total cases

```
 public static Map<String, Long> loadData() {
        String pathFile1 = "./locations.csv";
        String pathFile2 = "./full_data.csv";
        String row;
        try {

            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile1));
            List<Long> totalCases = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = row.split(",");
                totalCases.add(Long.parseLong(split[4])); // total at position 5
            }
            csvReader.close();

            csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile2));
            Map<String, Long> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            int i = 0;
            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = row.split(",");
                String continent = split[2]; // continent at position 3
                map.put(continent, map.getOrDefault(continent, 0L) + totalCases.get(i));
                i++;
            }
            csvReader.close();

            return map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give the headlines of how I would do it:

1. I would create a class from the csv1 format data, and another for csv2 format data.
   Class derived from csv1 would look like

```
Class CasesStatisticData{
    Date date;
    String location;
    long new_cases;
    long new_deaths;
    long total_cases;
    long total_deaths;
}
```

and from csv2

```
Class CountryData{
    String name
    String location
    String continent
    long population_year
    long population
}
```

2. I would create one ArrayList for each class
3. For each csv, for each line, I would create a new Object of the class associated to that csv and put that object on the list associated with that csv
4. I would create a TreeMap for each relation that I want. For example: you want each continent to be mapped on a list of countries. I would create `TreeMap<String, List<CountryData>> countriesByContinents`
5. I would iterate on that TreeMap keys, for each key, would count the total data on the list it is mapped.

Comment: I recommend against using the `Date` class. It’s poorly designed and long outdated. You probably want `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice @OleV.V.